# File name of Package Uploaded To Octopus-Deploy

Tags: octopus-deploy

Our build server creates a zip file after building our Angular 2 app and uploads it to Octopus using the Curl command.

The filename format we use is

```
app.1.0.0.buildNumber-branch.zip
```

Does this filename have to follow a certain pattern for Octopus to accept it?

Octopus Deploy 3.3.11

Answer (score 1):

For Octopus 3.4 and above, the version number must correspond to [Semver 2.0](http://semver.org/spec/v2.0.0.html).

For your version of Octopus (3.3.11), your version number should be a [SemVer 1.0](http://semver.org/spec/v1.0.0.html) version number. To make it easy, you should have three digits followed by a dash and prerelease tag. Try:

- `app.1.0.0-buildNumber-branch.zip` if you want the buildnumber to be part of the prerelease tag, OR
- `app.1.0.buildNumber-branch.zip` if you don't

More information [in the Octopus Documentation](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Versioning+in+Octopus+Deploy)

Comment: I'm not sure if Octopus has changed since this answer was written (e.g. the link to documentation is broken) but I version my packages as shown by the OP (even without the `-branch`) and it works fine. AFAICT You only need to use SemVer if you want to take advantage of the Channel rules, and even then, the OPs format works fine.